# How is matches function returning false in Spring security?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I cant understand why my BCryptPasswordEncoder matches function is returning false here which results in the authentication failure. 
I am using hibernate and Spring5 and when i encode my password, after matching it returns false.

```
String randomPassword="admin";

logger.info("Random Password " + randomPassword);

String encodedPassword=bCrypt.encode("randomPassword"); 
logger.info("Encoded Random Password " + encodedPassword);

Boolean b = bCrypt.matches(randomPassword, encodedPassword);

System.out.println("This should be true( " + b + " )");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You encode the wrong value.

Line

`String encodedPassword=bCrypt.encode("randomPassword");`

should be

`String encodedPassword=bCrypt.encode(randomPassword);`.